# How do I import an excel file and search for specific record using python and pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I’m trying to import an excel file and search for a specific record

Here’s what I have come up with so far, which keeps throwing error.

The excel spread sheet has two columns `Keyword` and `Description`, each keyword is around 10 characters max, and description is around 150 characters max.

I can print the whole sheet in the excel file without any errors using `print(df1)` but as soon as I try to search for a specific value it errors out.

**Error**

```
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (33,), (1,))
```

**Code**

```py
import pandas as pd

file = 'Methods.xlsx'
df = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = df.parse('Keywords')
lookup = df1['Description'].where(df1['Keyword']==["as"])
print (lookup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the filter syntax is like this

```py
df_filtered = df[df[COLUMN]==KEYWORD]
```

so in your case it'd be

```
lookup = df1[df1['Keyword'] == "as"]['Description']
```

or the whole code

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'Methods.xlsx'
df = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = df.parse('Keywords')
lookup = df1[df1['Keyword'] == "as"]['Description']
print (lookup)
```

---

### breaking it down:

```
is_keyword = df1['Keyword'] == "as"
```

this would return a series containing `True` or `False` depending on if the keyword was present.
then we can filter the dataframe to get those rows that have `True` with.

```
df_filtered = df1[is_keyword]
```

this will result in all the columns, so to get only the `Description` column we get it by

```
lookup = df_filtered['description']
```

or in one line

```
lookup = df1[df1['Keyword'] == "as"]['Description']
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfect, thanks for the fix and the break down (was very informative)!

Answer (score 1):

adding to the elaborate answer given by @Jimmar above:

Just for syntactical convenience, you could write the code like this:

```
lookup = df1[df1.keyword == "as"].Description
```

Pandas provides column name lookup like it is a member of DataFrame class( use of dot notation). Please note that the for using this way the column names should not have any spaces in them

Comment: That worked great as well, thanks for the alternate syntax!